# Check string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
String s = "http://www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]";
```

I need to check if this string has the words [VP_ANY] o [VP_ALL]. I tried something like this (and many combinations), but it doesn't work:

```
Pattern.compile("\b(\\\\[VP_ANY\\\\]|\\\\[VP_ALL\\\\])\b").matcher(s).matches()
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried the following:

s = "www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]";

System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\[VP_ANY\]").matcher(s).matches());

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\[VP_ANY\]", "A"));

The first 'System.out' returns false, and the second one returns the replacement correctly.

I'm escaping the "[" and "]" characters with 2 backslashes, but when I save the post just one is showed. But I'm using 2 ...

Comment: Should both words be present? In the given order? Why did you write "replace two words" in the title? What should they be replaced by?

Comment: You are searching for a literal `[VP_ANY]` and ~ALL?

Comment: Sorry for the title, I only need to know if any of the words are present, order is not important

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("\b(\\\\[VP_ANY\\\\]|\\\\[VP_ALL\\\\])\b").matcher(s).matches()
String s = "http://www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]";
                      ^^      ^^                ^^      ^
                      NoWB    NoWB              NoWB    WB
```

Your regex will not work because there is no word boundaray between `.` and `[`, between `]` and `.` and between `/` and `[`

Additionally I think you are wrong with the escaping, your word boundaries would need a backslash more and the others two less.

So, since the word boundaries are not working, you should be fine with

```
Pattern.compile("\\[VP_(?:ANY|ALL)\\])")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
\[VP_ANY\]|\[VP_ALL\]
```

My go at Java

```
try {
    boolean foundMatch = "www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]".matches("\\[VP_ANY\\]|\\[VP_ALL\\]");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: String s = "www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\[VP_ANY\\]|\\[VP_ALL\\]|").matcher(s).matches());  ---> false

Comment: @JBalaguero The regex is good. I think your java code is not what it should be.  I update my answer with my limited knowledge on how to do it in Java

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
try {
    boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(?i)\\bVP_(?:ANY|ALL)\\b");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**or this**

```
try {
    boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(?i)\\[VP_(?:ANY|ALL)\\]");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: String s = "www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bVP_(?:ANY|ALL)\\b").matcher(s).matches());  ---> false

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://www.[VP_ANY].com:8080/servlet/[VP_ALL]".replaceAll ("http://www.(\\[VP_ANY\\]).com:8080/servlet/(\\[VP_ALL\\])", "$1:$2")
res117: java.lang.String = [VP_ANY]:[VP_ALL]
```

If you're looking for a literal [, you have to mask it - else it will mean a group like [A-Z].

Now if you read the regex from a file or a JTextField at runtime, that's all. But if you write it to your source code, the compiler will see the \ and treat it as a general masking, which might be needed to mask quotes like in

```
char apo = '\''; 
String quote = "He said: \"Whut?\"";
```

So you have to mask it again, because only `"\\"` means `"\"`.

So, for development, to not get too much confused, it is a fine idea to have a simple GUI-App with 2 or 3 textfields for testing regexps. If you succeed, you only have to add another level of masking, but to develop them, you can keep this second level away.

*Divide et impera*, like the ancient roman programmers told us.